# Angular use behavior subject and http client

Tags: angular, typescript, http, components, behaviorsubject

In my application I use behavior subject. I have a service that makes an http call and puts the result in my behavior subject

My service :

```
  data$ = new BehaviorSubject({
      users: []
  });

  getUsers(){
      this.http()
      .subscribe((users: any) => {
          this.data$.next({...this.data$.value, users: users});
      });
  }
```

I call this service on my page but not the Oninit method. I trigger this call during the emi event of the child component in my page

My page :

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
  users$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  getUsers(event) {
    this.userService.getUsers();
    this.users$ = this.userService.data$;
  }
```

Passing the result to my child component :

```
    <app-table [config]="config" [entity]="(users$| async)?.users" 
 (onDataChange)="getUsers($event)"  class="row col-md-12">
    </app-table>
```

My problem is that the result did not pass to my child component. Yet I recover it well in my parent component

On the other hand if I load my data from the beginning in onInit these have passed to the child component

Comment: Can tell me what is `this.http()` ?

Comment: where emit onDataChange? when?

Comment: this.http is my http call to my api

Comment: onDataChange is emit in my child component (comp-table). it is set when a change appears in this component (example loading user preferences from the storage room), displaying a next page in the table

Comment: I would like to stay with my current archi and use the behavior subject. Also, between my component and my service I have a dispatcher. It is he who will return my subject behavior by calling the right service according to the action. I do not call my directemnet service

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it more simple  like this.

```
class service ... {
   private data$ = new BehaviorSubject();

   getData() {
      return data$.asObservable(); 
   }

   setData(users[]: users) {
      this.data$.next(users);
   }

}
```

In Component you can subscribe it or used directly in the template like you already have.

```
class component .. {
  users$: BehaviorSubject;
  constructor (private service: Service) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.users = this.service.gatData();
  }

 onDataChange(users) {
    this.service.setData(users);
 }
}
```

Comment: I would like to stay with my current archi and use the behavior subject. Also, between my component and my service I have a dispatcher. It is he who will return my subject behavior by calling the right service according to the action. I do not call my directemnet service

Comment: Plus data$ is composed of several things: user list, detail of a user ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for which your data doesn't get to the child component is that you're setting the users$ subject after initialization. The async pipe won't be triggered when changes occur.

In my opinion, a more reactive approach would look something like this:

**Service**:

```
export class UserService {
    refreshData$ = new Subject();
    data$ = this.refreshData$.pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.yourHttpCall())
    );
}
```

**Component**:

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {
    users$;
  
    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.users$ = this.userService.data$;
    }
  
    getUsers(event) {
      this.userService.refreshData$.next();
    }
}
```